# Loop returning 1.#QNAN0 in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I have to solve a Finite Difference problem (2d Heat Transfer, non-transient) in C, however when I try to put some operations in loop to include boundary conditions, it returns some strange values, other than float. What should I do? By the end, the script should calculate temperature fields in a composite medium. This code tries to put on evidence the temperature at surface T1[m-1][:].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( ){

    int i, j,k;
    int nx = 30;   // número de pontos em x
    int n = 10;
    int m=n;      // número de pontos em b1 e b2

    // Parâmetros de simulação

    float b1 = 0.01;         // altura do meio 1, m
    float b2 = 0.01;         // altura do meio 2, m
    float a  = 0.04;         // largura das placas, m
    float q  = -100000.0;      // fonte de calor na face superior [W/m2]
    float k1e = 54.0;          // condutividade térmica do material 1 [W/mC]
    float k2 = 54.0;           // condutividade térmica do material 1 [W/mC]
    float Tb = 0.0;            //temperatura de referência .C
    float hmax = 1000.0;

    float x[nx], y1[m], y2[n];
    float dx = a/(nx-1);
    float dy = b1/(m-1);
    y1[0] = b1;

    for (i=1; i<nx; i++){
        x[i] = x[i-1]+dx;
    }

    for (j=1; j<m; j++){
        y1[j]= y1[j-1] + dy;
        y2[j]= y2[j-1] + dy;
    }

    float T1[n][nx], T2[n][nx];
    float T1old[n][nx], T2old[n][nx];

    float hc[nx];

    for (i=0; i<nx;i++){
        if (x[i]<a/4)
            hc[i] = hmax;
        else if (x[i] > 3*a/4)
            hc[i] = hmax;
        else
            hc[i] = 0;

    }

    double err1 = 10.0;
    float diff = 10.0, maxdiff = 10.0;
    int contador = 0;

    float k1=k1e;

    while (contador<14000){  
        contador = contador +1;
        printf("%i \n", contador);
        for (i=0; i<nx;i++){
            for(j=0; j<n;j++){
                if (i==0){ //right -> includes j=0 and j=n-1
                    T1[j][i] = 0.25*(T1old[j-i][i] + T1old[j+i][i] + 2*T1old[i+1][j]);
                    T2[j][i] = 0.25*(T2old[j-i][i] + T2old[j+i][i] + 2*T2old[i+1][j]);
                }
                else if (i==nx-1){ //left -> includes j=0 and j=n-1
                    T1[j][i] = 0.25*(T1old[j-i][i] + T1old[j+i][i] + 2*T1old[i-1][j]);
                    T2[j][i] = 0.25*(T2old[j-i][i] + T2old[j+i][i] + 2*T2old[i-1][j]);
                }
                else if(j==0){ //bottom -> excludes j=0 and j=n-1
                    T1[j][i] = (1/(k1/dy + hc[i]))*(hc[i]*T2old[n-1][i] + (k1/dy)*(T1old[j+1][i]));
                    T2[j][i] = Tb;

                }
                else if(j==m-1){//top -> excludes i=0 and i=nx
                    T1[j][i] = 0.25*(2*T1old[j-1][i] -(2*q*dy/k1)+ T1old[j][i-1] + T1old[j][i-1]);
                    T2[j][i] = (-k1/k2)*(T1old[0][i]-T1[1][i]) + T2old[j-1][i];

                }
                else{ //interior nodes 0<i<nx and 0<j<n
                    T1[j][i] = 0.25*(T1old[j-1][i]+ T1old[j+1][i]+ T1old[j][i-1] + T1old[j][i-1]);
                    T2[j][i] = 0.25*(T2old[j-1][i]+ T2old[j+1][i]+ T2old[j][i-1] + T2old[j][i-1]);
                }

            }

        }
        for (j=0; j<m; j++){
            for (i=0; i<nx;i++){
                diff = abs(T1old[j][i] - T1[j][i]);
                T1old[j][i] = T1[j][i];
                T2old[j][i] = T2[j][i];
                if (diff>=maxdiff){
                    maxdiff = diff;
                }
            }
        }


        err1 = maxdiff;
        //printf("%i \n", contador);
   
    }

    for (i=0; i<nx;i++){
        printf("%f \n     ", T1[m-1][i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say this program "returns some strange values", that's a little inaccurate since it returns 0. I'm assuming you mean the contents of T1, T2, x, y, etc have some strange values.

You have a number of arrays that are not intitialized properly: x, y, T1, T2. Use memset to set the full arrays to a value. 

`    for (i=1; i<nx; i++){
        x[i] = x[i-1]+dx;
    }` 

Doesn't actually initialize x[0].

Comment: You are right, the code should be able to calculate temperatures values and store it in T1 and T2, which are arrays. When I try to check some values for T1[m-1][i], for example, it returns 1.#QNAN0 other than a float.  Is there other way to initialize it?

About the loop for (i=1; i<nx; i++){ x[i] = x[i-1]+dx; }, it actually starts in i=1, since x[0]=0.0 and the other elements are increased by dx from the latter.

Comment: You can initialize an array with void* r = memset(array_to_init, value, sizeof(float) * num_elements_in_array); 

However, beginning at line `float x[nx], y1[m], y2[n];`, you are declaring memory for these arrays but not defining the contents. 6 lines later, at the first iteration of 'for (i=1; i<nx; i++)', you assign the value of x[1] with an undefined value, x[0]. x[0] is never assigned. Therefore, every value in x is undefined because it depends on x[m-1]. 

C is not like Python or C# -- you should explicitly define every variable's value before you use it.

Comment: @FooAnon thanks for the help, I initialized the arrays and asssigned zeroes as their elements before entering the loop, by doing so the code worked